# Is a mathematical group also a mathematical "space"?

Tags: group-theory, vector-spaces, terminology

A [mathematical space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space_(mathematics)) is defined as:

> A set (sometimes called a universe) with some added structure.

Well, a [mathematical group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_(mathematics)) is:

> A set defined with a combining operation and some additional properties.

*A set with some added structure.*

Does this count as extra "structure", and could you then consider a group a type of "space"? How about rings and fields, can they be considered types of spaces? What about other objects like sheaves? Basically can any object which is a set with extra stuff around the set be considered a space, or is there something that space is unique from these other objects? If groups/rings/fields/sheaves are *not* spaces, why not?

Comment: Isn't this essentially the same as [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/174108/742)?

Comment: What you quote are not *definitions*; they are informal descriptions. There is a formal definition of what a "group" is, but the general notion of "space" is not a formal notion, and there is no precise, formal definition.

Comment: One can drive themselves mad over distinctions, so I prefer to think of intuitive appeal; certainly algebraic terms and the notion of a space overlap, but the reason why *space* was chosen for some objects is to highlight the natural geometry. A topology is an abstract set system, but a topological *space* introduces a context in which the topology lives. Analogously, a group acts on a space, but one would not say that group *is* a space.

Comment: The short answer is that a "space" isn't generally defined. We define various kinds of spaces, e.g. topological spaces, metric spaces, measure spaces, Euclidean spaces, vector spaces, etc. "Space" is rather an idea or concept rather than a single unified thing.

Comment: Is a group a set with additional structure?

Comment: It's not really worthwhile to fret too much about what some wikipedia writer meant, especially when it's one of those broad, intuitive, opening sentences of the wikipedia article.

Comment: By the author's definition the answer is yes. The language of groups has a binary function symbol and each group consists of a set and an interpretation of the binary function symbol, i.e. it defines multiplication. I really don't understand the other comments since the author defines what he means by a space.